# Find the number of injective functions $f\colon\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\to\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ such that $f(i)>f(i+1)$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, permutations

Let $n$ and $m$ be two natural numbers, $m\ge n\ge 2$ . Find the number of injective functions

$f\colon\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\to\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$

such that there exists a unique number

$i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ for which $f(i)>f(i+1)$

**My Attempt**

Number of injective functions should be $\binom{m}{n}(n!)$. But the question asks for number of injective functions such that for some specific $i$ we have $f(i)>f(i+1)$

Comment: Well, something's wrong. Say $m=4$, $n=3$. The total number of injective functions, even if we ignore the ordering condition, is only $24$. But the "given answer" formula gives $48$. So whoever gave you that answer made a mistake, or else you've made a mistake writing out the question or writing out the "given answer".

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: In the question there is one one case where $f(i) \gt f(i+1)$  In the title it seems to be always true.  As you edit, please make it consistent.

Comment: Check about Eulerian numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first focus on the case $m = n $:

We're then equivalently looking for bijections $f$ of $[n] := \{1,2,\dots, n\}$ with that ordering condition.

We can (uniquely) construct each of these $f$ in the following way:

1. Select the specific $i \in [n-1]$.

As $i$ should be unique, we have

$$f(1) < f(2) < \dots < f(i-1) < f(i) > f(i+1) < f(i+2) < \dots < f(n).$$

So, $f(i)$ needs to be bigger than $1, \dots, i$ for this to be true, therefore:

2. Select $f(i) := j \in \{i+1, \dots, n\}$.

The values of $f(1), f(2), \dots, f(i-1)$ need to be smaller than $j$, so they're in $[j-1]$.

By the ordering above, each subset of size $i-1$ of $[j-1]$ thus characterizes $f$ uniquely. (Why?)

Putting all of this together, the number of such bijections is

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} \sum_{j = i+1}^{n} \binom{j-1}{i-1} = \sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{i =1}^{j-1} \binom{j-1}{i-1} = \sum_{j = 1}^n (2^{j-1} - 1)  = 2^n - n -1.$$

For the general $m \geq n$ case, we first choose the subset of size $n$ of $[m]$ at the beginning on which you want to map onto.

So the number of injective functions with that ordering property is

$$\binom{m}{n} (2^n - n -1).$$

Edit:

For the $m = n$ case, you could also (more elegantly) just consider the injection
$$f \mapsto \{f(1), f(2), \dots, f(i_f) \}$$
($i_f$ denoting the unique index of $f$ with $f(i) > f(i+1)$) between the desired functions and subsets of $[n]$.
By our observations above, it should be clear that this is indeed an injective function. It should also be clear that the only subsets of $[n]$ which are not mapped onto are exactly $\emptyset, [1], [2], \dots, [n]$. So in the $m =n$ case the number of the desired functions is

$$2^n - (n+1) = 2^n - n - 1.$$